# The old value always retain in the textbox modal popup and Can't get the fresh value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I know that there is a lot solution on my problem and I tried some of them,
I also tried this one

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').find('textarea,input').val('');
});
```

but not working

and I even tried this code `$('.modalclass').remove();`

and also this one `$("#myModal")[0].reset();`

```
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Employees Record</h2> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Employee</button><br /><br />
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Age
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        State
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Country
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Employee</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="hello">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="EmployeeId">ID</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeID" placeholder="Id" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Age">Age</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Age" placeholder="Age" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="State">State</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="State" placeholder="State"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Country">Country</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Country" placeholder="Country"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Add();">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="Update();">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
```

here's my Script code

```
//function for updating employee's record
function Update() {
    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var empObj = {
        EmployeeID: $('#EmployeeID').val(),
        Name: $('#Name').val(),
        Age: $('#Age').val(),
        State: $('#State').val(),
        Country: $('#Country').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Update",
        data: JSON.stringify(empObj),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            loadData();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            window.location.reload();

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

this is my fuction for clearing the textbox box but it miraculously not working on the edit/updated button.

```
//Function for clearing the textboxes
function clearTextBox() {
    $('#EmployeeID').val("");
    $('#Name').val("");
    $('#Age').val("");
    $('#State').val("");
    $('#Country').val("");
    $('#btnUpdate').hide();
    $('#btnAdd').show();
}
```

And this is for my edit and delete

```
 //Load Data function
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/List",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.EmployeeID + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Age + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.State + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.Country + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyID(' + item.EmployeeID + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="Delele(' + item.EmployeeID + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why in the world are you making an ajax call and then using `window.location.reload();` to completely refresh the page (the whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page). And your `loadData();` and `$('#myModal').modal('hide');` code is pointless since you are on a new page

Comment: Is this question in any way related to any of your tags? It all seems to be javascript.

Comment: @john, It's related to JQuery also....

Comment: @Aria That's true. I was more trying to point out that tags for C#, ASP.NET, etc. are irrelevant when this appears to be a purely javascript/jquery issue.

Comment: which version of bootstrap you used. it's working on 3.3.7.

Comment: @john, Exactly true, they are irrelevant there is no something relevant to ASP.Net, then someone can edit it and remove  them...

Comment: @Aria I was trying to educate OP that it isn't necessary to tag every technology you're working with, and that it's better to tag the technologies you are working with re your specific question. Why do you end every sentence with "..."? Are you trying to get across some message that you're not saying? Don't you understand that I was simply trying to inform OP how to better use the site?

Comment: pandian_Snkl it's v3.3.6

Comment: it's working on google and firefox but not in Microsoft edge